# Is it possible to do a search for videos updated after date? [YouTube-Data-Api]

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am wondering if it is possible to get a list of videos that have been updated after a specified date? I am writing an application that helps users manage their videos titles, thumbnails, tags, descriptions, etc. This app really targets content creators that put out episodic content on a set schedule but also includes data of past videos. I am currently able to retrieve videos but I don't want to have to retrieve every video at the start of the application. It's both costly as far as the quota is concerned and time consuming. What I would like to do, is retrieve every video when the application starts up for the first time and store the data (done) and then any time after that, retrieve only new videos and/or videos that have been updated since the last date checked. If this is possible please let me know how I would go about this.

If not and a Google engineer happens to see this, this functionality would make for a very useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` from ressource [search.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list).

> The publishedAfter parameter indicates that the API response should
>   only contain resources created after the specified time. The value is
>   an RFC 3339 formatted date-time value (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). (string)
>
> The publishedBefore parameter indicates that the API response should
>   only contain resources created before the specified time. The value is
>   an RFC 3339 formatted date-time value (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). (string)

Comment: Sadly, the publishedAfter parameter only represents the day and time that a video resource is created and is updated when the video resource goes public. The purpose of the application I am writing is for convenience and organization. The particular piece of the app I am currently implementing is a calendar that shows when videos have gone public and when videos are scheduled to publish. As far as I can tell, there is currently no way to search by piblishAt which would be a viable option in combination with search by publishedAt.

Comment: I did a test with this just verify what is returned and realized that the publishedAt is returned as the date that the video resource is created and not the date when it was made public.