# YouTube Data API v3: How to filter ALL of a user's videos by date?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of an authenticated user's videos that were uploaded within a specific date range, regardless of status (private, unlisted, public, etc...) Looking at the API documentation, it appears that the only relevant endpoints that accept dates as query parameters are the `/search` and `/activities` endpoints.

However, when attempting to use the `publishedAfter` or `publishedBefore` parameters of these endpoints, the responses only include public videos. I've tried alternatively setting the `mine` and `forMine` parameters vs. `channelId` of the authenticated user's channel, but the result is the same. Additionally, attempting to use the `/search` endpoint with `publishedAfter` or `publishedBefore` and `forMine==true` returns a 400 error specifying an invalid combination of filters.

Is there any way to filter ALL of a user's videos by date via API? I've looked through similar questions, and the general response is to use `order` and `maxResults` to do the filtering in the response. I'd like to avoid this if at all possible due to the fact that the potential users of my application have fairly large numbers of videos (~10,000), which makes response filtering a highly inefficient method.

Example request to `/search` using `forMine==true` and dates:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?access_token={token}&part=snippet&forMine=true&publishedAfter=2018-04-01T04:00:00.000Z&publishedBefore=2018-05-17T04:00:00.000Z&type=video`

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.search",
                "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
                "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set either the <code>forContentOwner</code> or <code>forMine</code> parameters to <code>true</code>. You must also set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters.",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": ""
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set either the <code>forContentOwner</code> or <code>forMine</code> parameters to <code>true</code>. You must also set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters."
    }
}
```

This same request without the `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` parameters returns all of the user's videos as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098906

Comment: @noogui: that is indeed related, but my question is more about how to filter a user's by date videos regardless of upload status. There doesn't currently seem to be a way to filter all of a user's videos (including private) by date.